# Does bitwise inclusive OR with assignment operator have advantages over typical assignment in java?

Tags: java, performance, bitwise-or, compound-assignment

When looking at some code on one or another git, sometimes I can see that devs use bitwise inclusive OR compound assignment operator (`|=`) where simple assignment would be enough. Unfortunately, I don't have any code with this solution at hand, so I'll try to describe it as best I can.

Let's say, we have the following code in java:

```java
boolean found = false;
for (String s : stringSet) {
    if (s == null || s.equals("")) {
        found |= true; // <== this line
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("No interesting string found");
}
```

I ask only about the pointed line. Why people do it this way? I understand that we can have a really great amount of data, billions or trillions to iterate over. But does the pointed line changes the efficiency so dramatically? Would it be noticeably slower for a lot of data, if I change it to simple assignment: `found = true;`?

I don't exclude the possibility that not a speed is the main argument, but it seemed most meaningful to me.

And yes, I know this code can be converted to method or streams, but it's only a simplification of a code where it would be far more complicated etc. We can assume that before the pointed line (or even before `if`), there are tons of code that do something meaningful. Please, don't suggest something like "use streams instead", because I know how to java advanced already. I'd like to understand the phenomenon of this somehow enigmatic solution using bitwise inclusive OR.

Comment: "*Why people do it this way?"* - Why not ask the author?

Comment: I’ve never seen this way before.  It is most likely a personal habit of the author.  If seen in a code review I would flag it.

Comment: Please link to GitHub code.